# Enforce key and value types of non-indexed members

Tags: typescript

I have a function which can take any object literal so long as all of the values in the object are strings:

```
function getFirstLetters(obj: { [key: string]: string }): string[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key][0]);
}
```

This works well for any indexed type, the problem arises when I try to use non-indexed objects:

```
interface SomeData {
    user: string;
    loc: string;
}

const someData: SomeData = {
    user: "coolGuy42",
    loc: "New York",
};

function getFirstLetters(obj: { [key: string]: string }): string[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key][0]);
}

// Argument of type 'SomeData' is not
// assignable to parameter of type
// '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
// Index signature is missing in type 'SomeData'.
getFirstLetters(someData);
```

The error is straightforward - I have specifically requested that the function validate `obj` based on it having an index signature, NOT on the type of its values alone.

**Is there any way to make my function work with all objects with a uniform value type *without* asking anyone who uses it to include an index signature in their interface?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and require the input parameter to be any type whose known properties are all strings:

```
function getFirstLetters<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(obj: T): string[] {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key][0]); // error
}
```

But the compiler (rightly) complains that it doesn't know what `obj[key]` might be.  After all, the *known* keys of `T` are `string`-valued, but types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  A value of type `{foo: string}` might have any number of extra properties.  We know that its `foo` property is a `string`, but for all we know it might have a `bar` property that's a `number`.

If you are sure that only exact-like types will be passed to `getFirstLetters`, then you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that you are doing something safe:

```
function getFirstLetters<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(obj: T): string[] {
  // no error now
  return (Object.keys(obj) as (Array<keyof T>)).map(key => obj[key][0]);
}
```

And it should work as you expect when you call it:

```
getFirstLetters(someData); // no error
```

And it will reject values with known properties whose values are not `string`s:

```
getFirstLetters({a: "a", b: 23}); // error on b, not a string
```

But again, keep in mind that you can pass it some things with unknown non-string properties that will cause problems at runtime:

```
const whoopsie: SomeData = Object.assign({}, someData, { oops: null });
// whoopsie is a SomeData with an extra "oops" property that the 
// compiler has explicitly forgotten about

getFirstLetters(whoopsie); // no compiler error
// but calls null[0] at runtime and explodes!!
```

It's up to you if you care about those edge cases and how to deal with them if so.  Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: huh... so this certainly solves the above problem, but not my actual problem (I simplified it a bunch with a function for brevity).  I'll have to rephrase in a separate question.